# Is the meaning of “en effet” closer to English’s “indeed” or “in effect”?

Tags: traduction, anglais

I've seen the phrase "en effet" beginning a French sentence on occasion, and I was wondering whether it was closer to the meaning of the English word "indeed" or the phrase "in effect" - or perhaps it can have both senses? In English the two have a somewhat different meaning. "Indeed" emphasizes something previously mentioned:

> I like watching tennis. Indeed, I went to Wimbledon last year.

Whereas "in effect" means that something has a particular outcome which may not be obvious, or stated explicitly previously:

> Smoking is unhealthy in all sorts of ways. In effect, it's a slow means of suicide.

Which meaning is the French phrase closer to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say that it is closer to *indeed*, but perhaps not as broad. For instance, one wouldn't say

> *J'aime voir du tennis. En effet je suis allé à Roland-Garros l'an dernier.*

but rather

> *J'aime regarder du tennis. De fait je suis allé à Roland-Garros l'an dernier.*

But as a one-word sentence I think it to be a good translation

> « *Tu es allé à Roland-Garros l'an dernier ?*
>
> — *En effet.* »

*In effect* is closer to *en fait*

> *Fumer est très mauvais pour la santé. En fait, c'est un lent suicide.*

**Note** : I have edited my answer according to Gilles', but his and not mine should be chosen imho — though he's not the fastest cow-boy in the west.

Comment: I think that "justement" is more natural than "par exemple" in that example, and that "regarder" ("active") is better than "voir" ("passive").

Comment: @Axioplase Indeed

Comment: @Evpok En effet.

Answer (score 10):

Both French and English have several phrases derived from a verb meaning *do* (*faire*). Their meanings overlap to some extent.

***En [effet](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/effet)*** generally introduces a clarification. This can correspond to some of the uses of *indeed*. In this meaning, ***[effectivement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/effectivement)*** is effectively a synonym.

> I felt lost, and indeed I was lost.
>   *Je me sentis perdu, et je l'étais en effet.* (Eugène Fromentin)

*Indeed* can also indicate confirmation or agreement. *En effet* and (more commonly, I think) *effectivement* can be used for that as well.

> Was it you I saw in London yesterday? — Indeed I was in London yesterday, so that could have been me.
>   *Est-ce toi que j'ai vu à Londres hier ? — Effectivement, j'étais à Londres hier, donc il se peut que ce fût moi.*

Sometimes *indeed* introduces a reinforcement. *En effet* cannot perform that task; *de fait* or *par exemple* are possible translations.

> I like watching tennis. Indeed, I went to Wimbledon last year.
>   *J'aime regarder le tennis. De fait, je suis allé à Roland Garros cette année.*

*In fact* can introduce a clarification (overlapping with *indeed), but most often the clause that contains *in fact* extends the clause it illustrates in some manner. Then *en effet* cannot be used; ***en fait*** or ***de fait**** are possibilities (*par le fait* and *dans le fait* are others, but they are rare and dated). There is a nuance between *en fait* and *de fait*: *en fait* can convey opposition (there may be a difference between theory and practice), whereas *de fait* does not (practice confirms theory). Also, *en fait* insists on the passive aspect of *fact* (something is true), whereas *de fait* insists on the active aspect of *fact* (something happens).

> Gravity tells us that objects fall, and in fact if you drop a stone, it falls.
>   *La pesanteur nous dit que les objets tombent, et de fait, si on lâche une pierre, elle tombe.*
>
> In our experiment, we saw the stone fall. In fact, the law of gravity tells us that stones always fall.
>   *Dans notre expérience, nous avons pu observer que la pierre est tombée. En fait* or *de fait, la loi de la pesanteur énonce que les pierres tombent toujours.*
>
> In our experiment, we saw the stone fall. In fact, this is a general phenomenon called gravity.
>   *Dans notre expérience, nous avons pu observer que la pierre est tombée. En fait, il s'agir d'un phénomène général appelé pesanteur.*
>
> Smoking is unhealthy in all sorts of ways. In effect, it's a slow means of suicide. (or: it's effectively a means of suicide.)
>   *Fumer est mauvais pour la santé pour beaucoup de raisons. De fait, c'est une méthode de suicide lente.*
>
> Smoking is unhealthy in all sorts of ways. In fact [or: in truth], it's a slow means of suicide.
>   *Fumer est mauvais pour la santé pour beaucoup de raisons. En fait [or: en vérité], c'est une méthode de suicide lente.*

*En fait* can go as far as generalizing the discussion and reversing an assertion.

> I'm not sure if I saw him yesterday… In fact, I remember now: I haven't seen him all week.
>   *Je ne suis pas sûr de l'avoir vu hier... En fait, je me souviens maintenant : je ne l'ai pas vu de la semaine.*

When *en fait* has a concessive aspect, *à vrai dire* (“to tell the truth”) is another possible formulation.

> I don't know who won, and in fact I don't care.
>   *Je ne sais pas qui a gagné, et à vrai dire peu m'importe.*

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it is much more discursive and informative than the topic owner-accepted one.  This is a very tricky subject in French study and I welcome anyone who actually takes the time to explain it fully (if that's possible with this topic!)

Answer (score 5):

"En effet" is closer to "indeed."

Comment: So how would you say something like "in effect"?

Comment: @Jez I would say «En conséquence»

Comment: I would rather say “en pratique”. Not an exact match for “in effect” though.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez you're certainly right, the definition could be [in actuality](http://thesaurus.com/browse/in+effect)

Answer (score 0):

The expression `en effet` can be translated by `indeed` or sometimes `by the way`, but it would be a mistake to translate it by `in effect`.